# History question: Left and Right padding

Tags: history, ethereum-design

from:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/abi-spec.html#encoding-of-indexed-event-parameters

> bytesNN types are padded on the right while uintNN / intNN are padded on the left.

I would really love to understand why it was designed this way.

Comment: A wild guess: Byte types correspond to zero-terminated strings, so the zeros must be added on the right in order to allow an easy conversion. For integer types, padding on the left is equivalent to Little-Endian architecture, which is a lot more common than Big-Endian architecture.

Comment: @goodvibration I also think that's the right intuition, except you probably meant Big-Endian (adding 0s on the left makes more sense in big-endian: 00000020 means 20). Ethereum is big-endian, see the yellow paper for eg.